# ANR because of AdMob (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite)

Tags: android, admob

I see lots of ANRs because of AdMob (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite) in Google Play Console. The AdMob version is `com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3`.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this issue?

Here is the log:

```
"main" tid=1 Waiting 
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x75c17870 self=0x7088414c00
  | sysTid=15865 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x710e3c2548
  | state=S schedstat=( 182206776470 51362492841 457089 ) utm=14097 stm=4123 core=5 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fc705c000-0x7fc705e000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method)
- waiting on <0x0c968d7c> (a com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.j)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.j.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30004@30004.238272502.238272502:17)
- locked <0x0c968d7c> (a com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.j)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.h.b (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30004@30004.238272502.238272502:1)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.video.exoplayer1.f.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30004@30004.238272502.238272502:9)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.video.exoplayer1.f.b (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30004@30004.238272502.238272502:3)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.video.o.run (unavailable)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at aai.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30004@30004.238272502.238272502)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.e.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30004@30004.238272502.238272502:1)
  at aai.dispatchMessage (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30004@30004.238272502.238272502)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:280)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6748)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
"Jit thread pool worker thread 0" tid=2 Native 
"Jit thread pool worker thread 0" daemon prio=5 tid=2 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x14dc0000 self=0x708160e000
  | sysTid=15870 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7081b984f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 7120467166 4417943456 11222 ) utm=566 stm=146 core=6 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7081a9a000-0x7081a9c000 stackSize=1021KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000001f22c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 00000000000d744c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
  #02  pc 00000000004aa70c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPool::GetTask(art::Thread*)+260)
  #03  pc 00000000004a9c74  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+124)
  #04  pc 00000000004a9734  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)+148)
  #05  pc 00000000000923b0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
  #06  pc 0000000000023bf8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"ReferenceQueueDaemon" tid=4 Waiting 
"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=4 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x14dc0440 self=0x707fd70c00
  | sysTid=15873 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x70706bd4f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 919820191 192644883 1360 ) utm=59 stm=32 core=4 HZ=100
  | stack=0x70705ba000-0x70705bc000 stackSize=1041KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method)
- waiting on <0x051e3605> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
  at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal (Daemons.java:178)
- locked <0x051e3605> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
  at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run (Daemons.java:103)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
"FinalizerDaemon" tid=5 Waiting 
"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=5 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x14dc0518 self=0x707fd71800
  | sysTid=15874 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x70705b74f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 423748589 274637909 2036 ) utm=37 stm=5 core=6 HZ=100
  | stack=0x70704b4000-0x70704b6000 stackSize=1041KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method)
- waiting on <0x0f30b65a> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:422)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove (ReferenceQueue.java:188)
- locked <0x0f30b65a> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove (ReferenceQueue.java:209)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal (Daemons.java:232)
  at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run (Daemons.java:103)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" tid=6 Waiting 
"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x14dc0650 self=0x707fd72400
  | sysTid=15875 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x70704b14f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 20386195 41230836 227 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x70703ae000-0x70703b0000 stackSize=1041KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method)
- waiting on <0x02e9408b> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepUntilNeeded (Daemons.java:297)
- locked <0x02e9408b> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.runInternal (Daemons.java:277)
  at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run (Daemons.java:103)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
"Binder:15865_1" tid=7 Native 
"Binder:15865_1" prio=5 tid=7 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x14dc0748 self=0x7088484400
  | sysTid=15877 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x70701a74f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 177113540 245706304 1494 ) utm=9 stm=8 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x70700ac000-0x70700ae000 stackSize=1009KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000007cdbc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
  #01  pc 000000000002cb80  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+132)
  #02  pc 000000000005cd88  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+244)
  #03  pc 000000000005cf64  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+24)
  #04  pc 000000000005d6ac  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+64)
  #05  pc 000000000007fc74  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::PoolThread::threadLoop()+24)
  #06  pc 00000000000100dc  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+284)
  #07  pc 00000000000b44a8  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140)
  #08  pc 00000000000923b0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
  #09  pc 0000000000023bf8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"Binder:15865_2" tid=9 Native 
"Binder:15865_2" prio=5 tid=9 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x14dc07d0 self=0x70885e8c00
  | sysTid=15878 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x70700a94f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 181601435 190235002 1460 ) utm=11 stm=7 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x706ffae000-0x706ffb0000 stackSize=1009KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000007cdbc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
  #01  pc 000000000002cb80  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+132)
  #02  pc 000000000005cd88  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+244)
  #03  pc 000000000005cf64  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+24)
  #04  pc 000000000005d6d8  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+108)
  #05  pc 000000000007fc74  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::PoolThread::threadLoop()+24)
  #06  pc 00000000000100dc  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+284)
  #07  pc 00000000000b44a8  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140)
  #08  pc 00000000000923b0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
  #09  pc 0000000000023bf8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"Binder:15865_3" tid=10 Native 
"Binder:15865_3" prio=5 tid=10 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x14dc0858 self=0x7081615800
  | sysTid=15879 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x706ffab4f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 178396756 228504652 1723 ) utm=8 stm=9 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x706feb0000-0x706feb2000 stackSize=1009KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000007cdbc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
  #01  pc 000000000002cb80  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+132)
  #02  pc 000000000005cd88  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+244)
  #03  pc 000000000005cf64  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+24)
  #04  pc 000000000005d6d8  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+108)
  #05  pc 000000000007fc74  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::PoolThread::threadLoop()+24)
  #06  pc 00000000000100dc  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+284)
  #07  pc 00000000000b44a8  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140)
  #08  pc 00000000000923b0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
  #09  pc 0000000000023bf8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"Profile Saver" tid=11 Native 
"Profile Saver" daemon prio=5 tid=11 Native
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x14dc08e0 self=0x70885b3400
  | sysTid=15881 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x706f3894f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 1891158552 178338016 742 ) utm=176 stm=13 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x706f28e000-0x706f290000 stackSize=1009KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000001f22c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 00000000000d744c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
  #02  pc 0000000000322854  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ProfileSaver::Run()+384)
  #03  pc 0000000000325c4c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ProfileSaver::RunProfileSaverThread(void*)+92)
  #04  pc 00000000000923b0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
  #05  pc 0000000000023bf8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"FirebaseInstanceId" tid=13 Waiting 
"FirebaseInstanceId" prio=5 tid=13 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x14dc0968 self=0x7088482c00
  | sysTid=15886 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x706efc04f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 3404269 2267968 18 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=7 HZ=100
  | stack=0x706eebd000-0x706eebf000 stackSize=1041KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method)
- waiting on <0x057d0568> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$ (Thread.java:2137)
- locked <0x057d0568> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:358)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:190)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2059)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1120)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:849)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.a.run (unavailable:6)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
"Queue" tid=20 Waiting 
"Queue" prio=10 tid=20 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x14dc1140 self=0x707fcd9800
  | sysTid=15895 nice=-8 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x706e83c4f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 11115837 2085936 26 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=5 HZ=100
  | stack=0x706e739000-0x706e73b000 stackSize=1041KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method)
- waiting on <0x04512d81> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$ (Thread.java:2137)
- locked <0x04512d81> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:358)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:190)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2059)
  at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take (PriorityBlockingQueue.java:548)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.c.a (SourceFile:197)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.c.b (SourceFile:236)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.c.a (SourceFile:65)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.c.take (SourceFile:46)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
"Queue" tid=21 Waiting 
"Queue" prio=10 tid=21 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x14dc1bf8 self=0x707fcdb000
  | sysTid=15897 nice=10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x706e32a4f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 21071511 16160467 91 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=5 HZ=100
  | stack=0x706e227000-0x706e229000 stackSize=1041KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method)
- waiting on <0x0533de26> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$ (Thread.java:2137)
- locked <0x0533de26> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:358)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:190)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2059)
  at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take (PriorityBlockingQueue.java:548)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.c.a (SourceFile:197)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.c.b (SourceFile:236)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.c.a (SourceFile:65)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.c.take (SourceFile:46)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
"Queue" tid=22 Waiting 
"Queue" prio=10 tid=22 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x14dc1cf8 self=0x707fcda400
  | sysTid=15896 nice=-8 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x706e4304f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 507919 969584 15 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=6 HZ=100
  | stack=0x706e32d000-0x706e32f000 stackSize=1041KB
  | held mutexes=
"Signal Catcher" tid=3 Runnable 
"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 Runnable
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x14dc0088 self=0x7088416400
  | sysTid=15872 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7081a974f0
  | state=R schedstat=( 60935885 3614426 25 ) utm=1 stm=5 core=7 HZ=100
  | stack=0x708199c000-0x708199e000 stackSize=1009KB
  | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
  #00  pc 00000000003c1e90  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+220)
  #01  pc 000000000048f44c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+352)
  #02  pc 00000000004a8ec8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+844)
  #03  pc 00000000004a1de4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*)+484)
  #04  pc 00000000004a1274  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool)+1036)
  #05  pc 00000000004a0d94  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::DumpForSigQuit(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&)+884)
  #06  pc 0000000000471208  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::DumpForSigQuit(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&)+188)
  #07  pc 000000000047cf78  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::HandleSigQuit()+1372)
  #08  pc 000000000047bc50  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::Run(void*)+256)
  #09  pc 00000000000923b0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
  #10  pc 0000000000023bf8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"HeapTaskDaemon" tid=8 
"HeapTaskDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=8 WaitingForTaskProcessor
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x14dd6c80 self=0x707e217000
  | sysTid=15876 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x70703ab4f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 12858851765 601057066 3943 ) utm=1131 stm=154 core=6 HZ=100
  | stack=0x70702a8000-0x70702aa000 stackSize=1041KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000001f22c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 00000000000d744c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
  #02  pc 000000000022d3b4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::GetTask(art::Thread*)+440)
  #03  pc 000000000022dc48  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::RunAllTasks(art::Thread*)+96)
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks (Native method)
  at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal (Daemons.java:475)
  at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run (Daemons.java:103)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am too having the same issue, Looks like google has a known bug and open issue of this ANR.

Please check : https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/issues/143

Comment: They are not the same. I have reported it to Google: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-admob-ads-sdk/ANR|sort:date/google-admob-ads-sdk/rCZMplesYEc/p6VpFfr2BgAJ

Comment: Can you please tell us that how we can remove those issue? or Google will automatically remove it